# How to write a custom rolling function for python dask?

Tags: python, dask

Searching on google, I found that dask have a wrapper for pandas rolling functions. But I need a simple example of a custom rolling function that use the `n` previous values to compute the current in dask.

Let's say I need the `3` previous values of the `X` column of my dataframe to compute the current value of the `Y` column with this formula:

```
y(i)= x(i-1) + 2*x(i-2) - 3*x(i-3)
```

[image: equation example]